# AVAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: Cannot call method when status is 0

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

Well I happily discovered that my app crash on the version downloaded from the Apple AppStore whereas it never did before. looking at the log I get the exception

`AVAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: Cannot call method when status is 0`

Obviously this error does not occur in debug mode. But it never did in release mode before in a code that was shipped with another app and available on the appStore.

Could it be the `directoryForTemporaryFiles` added in `iOS 8` the responsible for this status 0 ?

Comment: Maybe you should call startWriting first and if that method returns true/YES, then call startSessionAtSourceTime?
You can also look at RosyWriter Apple sample https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: indeed I wasn't calling start writing because the call was wrapped in an NSPArameterAssert which is not compiled in release mode

Comment: @NicolasManzini Any solution?

Comment: call startWriting before calling startSessionAtSourceTime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `startWriting()` method before `startSessionAtSourceTime()` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
[AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:writePath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:nil];
```

Maybe the issue is on fileType. Make sure to select the correct filetype.